# Making an ensemble learning function based on XGboost models

Tags: r, function, machine-learning, xgboost, ensemble-learning

I'm trying to make a robust function that will train a stacked ensemble model using multiple xgboost base learners and a random forest metalearner. This is the code:

```
super_train <- function(data_list, n_models = 10, cpus = 32) {
  
  # Set up parallel processing
 # parallelStartSocket(cpus = cpus)
  
  # Prepare data
  train <- data_list[[1]]
  test <- data_list[[2]]
  train[,1] <- factor(train[,1])
  test[,1] <- factor(test[,1])
  task <- makeClassifTask(data = train, target = "CR")
  print(task$type)
  
  # Create base learners
  base_learners <- list()
  for (i in 1:n_models) {
    ctrl <- makeTuneControlMBO()
    lrn <- makeLearner("classif.xgboost", predict.type = "prob")
    ps <- makeParamSet(
      makeDiscreteParam("booster", values = c("gbtree", "gblinear")), 
      makeNumericParam("eta", lower = 0.01, upper = 0.08), 
      makeIntegerParam("max_depth", lower = 2L, upper = 11L), 
      makeNumericParam("alpha", lower = 0L, upper = 8),
      makeNumericParam("lambda", lower = 0L, upper = 8),
      makeNumericParam("gamma", lower = 0L, upper = 8),
      makeNumericParam("min_child_weight", lower = 2L, upper = 8L), 
      makeNumericParam("subsample", lower = 0.5, upper = 1), 
      makeNumericParam("colsample_bytree", lower = 0.5, upper = 1),
      makeNumericParam("scale_pos_weight", lower = 1, upper = 10)
    )
    
    auc <- makeMeasure(id = "classif.auc", name = "Area under ROC curve", minimize = FALSE,
                       fun = function(truth, pred, lev = NULL, model = NULL) {
                         require(pROC)
                         response <- factor(truth, levels = lev)
                         prediction <- pred[, lev[2]]
                         roc_obj <- roc(response, prediction)
                         auc_obj <- auc(roc_obj)
                         return(auc_obj)
                       })
    
    
    resampling_desc <- makeResampleDesc("CV", iters = 10)
    res <- tuneParams(lrn, task, resampling = resampling_desc, measures = list(auc),
                      par.set = ps, control = ctrl)
    
    
    base_learners[[i]] <- res$learner
  }
  
  # Create meta-learner
  meta_lrn <- makeLearner("classif.randomForest", predict.type = "prob")
  meta_lrn$par.vals <- list(ntree = 100, mtry = sqrt(ncol(train)), importance = TRUE)
  
  # Create stacked ensemble
  stack_learner <- makeStackedLearner(base_learners, metalearner = meta_lrn)
  stack_learner$par.vals <- list(metalearner.control = list(ntree = 100))
  
  # Train stacked ensemble
  stack_model <- train(stack_learner, task)
  
  # Evaluate on test set
  test_pred <- predict(stack_model, newdata = test)$data
  
  # Stop parallel processing
 # parallelStop(cl)
  
  return(stack_model)
}
```

However, this is not working. I'm not really sure where the problem is, this is the error I keep getting:

```
Error in assert_factor(truth, min.len = 1L, n.levels = 2L, any.missing = FALSE) :
argument "truth" is missing, with no default
```

I did some extensive hyperparameter tunning. I tune the hyperparameters of each xgboost learner using cross-validation and the parameter search space. Then I create a stacked learner using `makeStackedLearner()` with the xgboost learners as the base learners and a random forest as the metalearner. Then I train the ensemble on the training set with 10-fold cross validation and create a `TaskClassif` object for the test data, predict the target variable for the test data using the ensemble model, and just return the trained ensemble model. That's the whole story.

But what is the problem with the code? why isn't it working?

Here is a small share of my training set:

```
structure(list(target = structure(c(1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L), levels = c("0", 
"1"), class = "factor"), Bone = c(0.68, 0.82, 0.6, 0.63, 
0.5, 0.72, 0.66, 0.58, 0.6, 0.6, 0.56, 0.7, 0.59, 0.55, 0.47, 
0.6, 0.64, 0.67, 0.62, 0.59), Blood = c(0.54, 0.65, 0.48, 
0.54, 0.22, 0.58, 0.51, 0.38, 0.46, 0.42, 0.3, 0.62, 0.4, 0.29, 
0.2, 0.48, 0.54, 0.55, 0.37, 0.46), Skin = c(0.77, 0.83, 
0.74, 0.75, 0.75, 0.78, 0.75, 0.76, 0.76, 0.76, 0.75, 0.76, 0.76, 
0.75, 0.74, 0.75, 0.76, 0.75, 0.75, 0.74), Brain = c(0.51, 
0.59, 0.46, 0.5, 0.33, 0.56, 0.49, 0.39, 0.45, 0.46, 0.37, 0.57, 
0.43, 0.37, 0.32, 0.47, 0.48, 0.55, 0.43, 0.47), Liver = c(0.58, 
0.62, 0.55, 0.58, 0.48, 0.58, 0.62, 0.5, 0.51, 0.55, 0.53, 0.65, 
0.54, 0.48, 0.46, 0.57, 0.57, 0.65, 0.59, 0.59), Stomach = c(0.58, 
0.65, 0.54, 0.59, 0.5, 0.61, 0.6, 0.51, 0.51, 0.55, 0.56, 0.61, 
0.55, 0.51, 0.47, 0.59, 0.55, 0.63, 0.57, 0.59), Heart = c(0.62, 
0.66, 0.55, 0.61, 0.44, 0.63, 0.58, 0.51, 0.55, 0.55, 0.46, 0.66, 
0.53, 0.47, 0.41, 0.56, 0.57, 0.64, 0.51, 0.56), T.cells = c(0.53, 
0.75, 0.5, 0.51, 0.47, 0.66, 0.52, 0.52, 0.53, 0.54, 0.47, 0.56, 
0.49, 0.48, 0.45, 0.51, 0.52, 0.55, 0.52, 0.53), B.cells = c(0.52, 
0.81, 0.46, 0.47, 0.39, 0.7, 0.49, 0.47, 0.5, 0.54, 0.41, 0.54, 
0.44, 0.43, 0.37, 0.48, 0.49, 0.53, 0.48, 0.52)), row.names = c("Pt1", 
"Pta101", "Pta106", "Ptc11", "Ptc17", "Ptc18", "Ptb2", "Ptm26", "Ptm28", 
"Pta29", "Pta3", "Pta34", "Ptb37", "Ptb38", "Ptb39", "Ptb4", "Ptc44", 
"Ptc46", "Ptb47", "Pta48"), class = "data.frame")
```

Comment: What version of `mlr` do you have?  The syntax for `makeStackedLearner` doesn't match [what is expected](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/mlr/versions/2.19.0/topics/makeStackedLearner) by mlr 2.19.